# The best English term for a made up, catchy code-name

Tags: word-request

What is the best English term for a made up, catchy code-name (typically, created spontaneously during a brainstorm meeting) for some new concept or prototype?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific term in English for that, but you could certainly use : code-name, alias, handle.